# Get slide after some animation in Aspose.Slides

Tags: c#, .net, aspose

One slide can contain many shapes with animations. I need to split one slide to many by each animation.
For example I have slide with 7 animations. After first animations occurs, I need to render this slide as new one and add it to the end of presentation. Is it possible using Aspose.Slides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can clone a shape and add it to another slide. Check the below pages in documentation.

1. [Cloning shapes in slides](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/slidesnet/Cloning+Shapes+in+Slides)
2. [Working with animations](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/slidesnet/Working+with+Animations)